# Requesting information regarding the star of Remphan

Tags: star-of-david

Is the Magen Dovid a later iteration of the star of Remphan or is this a misconception spread by ignorance and/or an anti-semitic agenda? The star of Remphan was a symbol that represented the Egyptian deity Chiun as spoken of in the Book of Amos. Xtians and anti-semites claim this is the origin of the Magen Dovid. I am wondering if this is the origin or is this false? The star of Remphan was identical to the Magen Dovid — two triangles. A general Google search will show what it looks like.

Comment: What is the star of Remphan?

Comment: It was a star that represented the Egyptian deity named Chiun mentioned in the Book of Amos.

Comment: All relevant information should be included in the question. What is this star? What did it look like? Why do you think the two stars are connected? Why do you think this might be a more plausible explanation for its origins? You phrase your question as if this was a claim you had heard somewhere - where did you hear it?

Comment: That Google search is only picking up pictures of Magen David’s... I think this is fine at this point. Voting to reopen. Anyway, I get the feeling that this is the same fallacy discussed in our [question about Tehillim 29](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87217/9682) - two things that are kind of similar therefore must be the same.

Comment: I think we never claimed the invention of this symbol.

Comment: If we never claimed its origination, from where did it originate? The star of Rempham existed in Egypt prior to the Exodus.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/what-is-the-source-of-the-magen-dovid-star-of-david?rq=1 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11810/how-did-the-star-of-david-become-iconic?rq=1